# virtual machine manager window shows no fonts on ubuntu 12.04 remote client

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualization

I am connecting via ssh to virtual machine manager on remote CentOS 6.2 serverand the virtual machine manager window opens but shows no fonts.

The text is just little Squares, cannot read anything on the window, so impossible to use the virtual machine manager.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well that's useful, mark me down but offer no comment at all. Very helpful! Whoever you are!

Comment: Your question is unclear and probably off-topic. Start by reading the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: Thanks for your illuminating wisdom it offers no benefit at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed xfonts as well as Liberation fonts on the host and the fonts now display (albeit weird looking). Obviously the CentOS minimal installation does not install the correct fonts required by Virtual Machine Manager.

Comment: dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts is necessary or all the fonts in virt-manager will show as squares: 
 
yum install dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts